# How can I add two boxes in minipages side by side?

Tags: boxes, minipage

I tried to create two boxes side by side in minipages but I don't know how to create them ? Any help is appreciated.[image]

[image]

```
\begin{minipage}[t]{5.5cm}
    \centerline{\textbf{TRƯỜNG ĐHSP TP.HCM}}
    \centerline{\textbf{Khoa Toán - Tin học}}
    \centerline{\rule{1.7in}{1pt}}
    \centerline{\textbf{Đề chính thức}}
    \centerline{(Đề thi có 01 trang)}
\end{minipage}\hspace{1.5cm}
\begin{minipage}[t]{11cm}
    \textbf{ĐỀ THI KẾT THÚC HỌC PHẦN}\\
    Tên học phần: \textbf{Tôpô đại cương}\\
    Mã học phần: MATH1410. \hspace{0.5cm} Số tín chỉ: 2\\
    Học kì I. \hspace{1cm} Năm học 2018 - 2019.\\
    Thời gian làm bài: \textbf{90 phút}
\end{minipage}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hope the below may helps:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{framed}
\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}[t]{5.5cm}
\begin{framed}
    \centerline{\textbf{TRU?NG ÐHSP TP.HCM}}
    \centerline{\textbf{Khoa Toán - Tin h?c}}
    \centerline{\rule{1.7in}{1pt}}
    \centerline{\textbf{Ð? chính th?c}}
    \centerline{(Ð? thi có 01 trang)}
\end{framed}
\end{minipage}\ignorespaces%\hspace{1.5cm}
\begin{minipage}[t]{11cm}
\begin{framed}
    \textbf{Ð? THI K?T THÚC H?C PH?N}\\
    Tên h?c ph?n: \textbf{Tôpô d?i cuong}\\
    Mã h?c ph?n: MATH1410. \hspace{0.5cm} S? tín ch?: 2\\
    H?c kì I. \hspace{1cm} Nam h?c 2018 - 2019.\\
    Th?i gian làm bài: \textbf{90 phút}
\end{framed}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

`\ignorespaces` does the trick!!

Comment: Thank you but it seems two boxes are seperated each other, not side by side. Are there any ways to link two boxes ?

Comment: @NguyenThy Please check the updated answer...

Comment: @NguyenThy Glad to hear that my suggestion works for you...you're always welcome...

Answer (score 9):

With a `tabularx`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|p{.1cm}cp{.3cm}|p{.3cm}Xp{.1cm}|}
\hline
&\rule{0pt}{1.4cm}\makecell{\textbf{TRƯỜNG ĐHSP TP.HCM}\\
    \textbf{Khoa Toán - Tin học}\\
    \rule{1.7in}{1pt}\\
    \textbf{Đề chính thức}\\
    (Đề thi có 01 trang)} 
&&&  
\makecell[l]{\textbf{ĐỀ THI KẾT THÚC HỌC PHẦN}\\
    Tên học phần: \textbf{Tôpô đại cương}\\
    Mã học phần: MATH1410. \hspace{0.5cm} Số tín chỉ: 2\\
    Học kì I. \hspace{1cm} Năm học 2018 - 2019.\\
    Thời gian làm bài: \textbf{90 phút}}&\\[1.1cm]
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. How can I add two vertical lines each side ?

Comment: \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|p{.1cm}cp{.3cm}|p{.3cm}Xp{.1cm}|} may helps you...

Comment: @NguyenThy See my renewed answer

Comment: It works. Thank you very much